# Wait for for loop to execute before returning value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to wait for all files to be loaded before uploading.

I am using Ionic 3, and Angular 5 to try and upload files from iOS and Android.

I have a list of files stored in storage. I retrieve the list of files, loop over them, read the file, and try to add each to formData. The function returns null because it is not waiting for the loop to finish. how can I fix this?

file-provider.ts

```js
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';

readonly directory = this.fileCtrl.dataDirectory;

constructor
(
private fileCtrl: File,
private storage: StorageProvider,
)

getFilesByFolderID(folderID): any {
    let formData = new FormData();
    let missingFiles = [];
    const path = `${this.directory}${folderID}`;
    // i have the names of the file and information about them in local storage 
    return this.storage.getFiles(folderID).then(data => {
      const files = data.files
      files.forEach(file => {
        this.fileCtrl.resolveDirectoryUrl(path).then(url => {
          this.fileCtrl.getFile(url, file.uniqName, {create: false}).then(entry => {
            entry.file( f => {
              formData.append('data', f, file.name);
              formData.append('type', file.type);
              formData.append('size', file.size);
              formData.append('icon', file.icon);
            });

          }).catch(err => {
            missingFiles.push(file.name);
            console.log("ERROR ", JSON.stringify(err));
          })
        }).catch(err => this.handleFileError(err));
      });
      // This is always empty
      return formData;
      });
}
```

Comment: return the formdata from inside the then.

Comment: @Shannon sorry where should I return it? If I do it earlier all of the files won't be loaded

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice the for each loop when i commented. You may need to use promise.all https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all or typescripts async/await in order to wait for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wait for all of the promises in your loop to resolve then return once that's done. This may need a tweak but should work for your purposes.

```
getFilesByFolderID(folderID): any {
    let formData = new FormData();
    let missingFiles = [];
    let promises: any[] = []
    const path = `${this.directory}${folderID}`;
    // i have the names of the file and information about them in local storage 
    this.storage.getFiles(folderID).then(data => {
      const files = data.files
      files.forEach(file => {
        let promise = this.fileCtrl.resolveDirectoryUrl(path).then(url => {
          this.fileCtrl.getFile(url, file.uniqName, {create: false}).then(entry => {
            entry.file( f => {
              formData.append('data', f, file.name);
              formData.append('type', file.type);
              formData.append('size', file.size);
              formData.append('icon', file.icon);
            });

          }).catch(err => {
            missingFiles.push(file.name);
            console.log("ERROR ", JSON.stringify(err));
          })
        }).catch(err => this.handleFileError(err));
        promises.push[promise];
      });
      });

      //this should wait for all promises to resolve
      Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
        return formData;

      })



}
```

Comment: Without getting more intimate with your code I can't provide an exact solution. Promise.all or async/await are solutions, you just need to research and apply one of the patterns to your specific case. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you put `return formData` directly after this code:

```
entry.file( f => {
    formData.append('data', f, file.name);
    formData.append('type', file.type);
    formData.append('size', file.size);
    formData.append('icon', file.icon);
});
return formData;
```

Also, the calling method should look like this because a Promise is returned from this method:

```
getFilesByFolderID(2).then((hi) => {console.log(hi)})
```

You might also want to read up on Promise.all()

Comment: Nope it doesn't work because the loop is still not finished. I am resolving the promise first in the calling method